# Difference between Long and long?

Tags: android, long-integer, notepad

I am going through the 2nd exercise of the android example the notepad app, I have this a question about the difference between Long and long that was used to define the mRowId.

The exercise is here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex2.html

And below is the code piece that I am having problem with:

```
public class NoteEdit extends Activity {

private Long mRowId; 
private EditText mTitleText;
private EditText mBodyText; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.note_edit);
    setTitle(R.string.edit_note);

    mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
    mBodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.body);
    Button confirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);

    mRowId = null;
```

When I declared mRowId with `long`, I got an error when I tried to set mRowId to null, the error is "type mismatch". But if I use `Long`, the error goes away. Why doesn't `long` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Long` is a wrapper class around the [primitive](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) `long`. Therefore `Long` is an object; objects can be `null`, primitives can not.

See the [`Long` class documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Long.html).

Answer (score 0):

`long` is primitive type and `Long` is boxed type of `long`. After auto-boxing feature is released in java the primitive `long` can be automatically converted to `Long`, which is an object.

But sometmimes this creates issue also. For example the below code is terribly slow:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Long sum = 0L;
    for(long i=0; i < Integer.MAX_VAL; i++){
        sum+=i;
    }
}
```

This is because the program unintentionally creating 2^31 objects unnecessarily because of capital L in `sum` declaration.